# How to check if post title already exists?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I followed [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52454666/1018804) and read [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title), finally I tried to apply the logic using `ajax`:

**On frontEnd:**

```
var ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
$("#publish").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : ajax_url,
    type: 'post',
    data: { 
      action: 'data_Publish', portfolioTitle: $("#portfolioTitle").val(), idsInput: $("#idsInput").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $("#titleSaveModal .modal-body").html("<p>Pubblicato</p>");
    }
  });
});
```

**On `function.php`**

```
function data_Publish() {
  $post_title = $_POST['portfolioTitle'];
  $post = array(
    'post_title'    => $post_title,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'page_template'  => 'portoflio.php'
  );
  if ( get_page_by_title( $post_title ) === null ) {
    echo "Already exists!";
  } else {
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'portfolio-ids', $_POST['idsInput'], true);
  }
  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_data_Publish', 'data_Publish');
```

But even if I give a same title, it will always publish a new post, meaning it is not finding out that title already exists, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: so what is in `get_page_by_title( $post_title )` ? is `$post_title` populated correctly? it's obvious your if statement is failing if wp_insert_post is being called

Comment: @Scuzzy " it's obvious your if statement is failing" yeah well, I know. `$post_title` is correct as I can see it inserting the post into the db with the same title

Comment: @msg sorry Just a typo on the question, corrected. Issue remains.

Comment: it's saving the posts with a new slug btw but the same title

Comment: @msg no way! I am using `equal comparison`, how did I miss that?!  Stupid. Thanks a lot, wanna put that into an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is backwards, `get_page_by_title( $post_title ) === null` means it doesn't exist, you just have to swap the `then` and `else` code blocks.

```
if ( get_page_by_title( $post_title ) === null ) {
  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
  add_post_meta($post_id, 'portfolio-ids', $_POST['idsInput'], true);
} else {
  echo "Already exists!";
}
```